# Python Flask-admin: flash is not working with Markup

Tags: python, flask, flask-admin

In one specific flash message, I need to use the HTML code in the Flask-admin. It is safe because it is my own message. I will post the important piece of code. I am using `flask_admin.contrib.sqla.ModelView` The following code snippet is not interpretable, it is just an important piece of code, but you can easily test it in your own app. Please, do not ask me why I need to do something like this, I am asking, because I have tried several things, but nothing worked. The only thing what was working was to change `flask-admin macro` `messages()` and add `safe` filter, but this is something I don't want to do in the `flask-admin`. Any idea, please?

```
# override
def on_model_change(self, form, model, is_created):
    if something_is_wrong():
        raise CustomException(
            'Something in the <b>entity</b> was wrong. Please check: ' +
            '<ul><li><a href="#">this</a></li><li><a href="#">and this</a></li></ul>'
        )

# override
def update_model(self, form, model):
    try:
        return super(CustomView, self).update_model(form, model)
    except CustomException, ce:
        self.session.rollback()
        flash(Markup(ce.message), category='error')

        return False
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override the template where flash message is rendered and put this in place

```
{{message|safe}}
```

Comment: Hi, yes, like I said, it was the way it worked as I expected. But early I didn't notice that the flash messages are in the block named `messages`. After your answer I have explored it again and finally I've found the block `messages` in the base template. So I've overrided it in the one template I needed and it is working correctly. Thank you.